# Elasticsearch complex query with priorities

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, e-commerce

I've got products with many prices based on available discounts and price lists with assigned priorities. The 'price' part mapping looks like this:

```
"price": {
    "properties": {
        "USD": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "amount": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "discount_id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "price_list_id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "priority": {
                    "type": "short"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The root property is currency (there might be more currencies, depends on a shop).
Real example of price:

```
"price": {
    "USD": [
        {
            "amount": 10.0,
            "price_list_id": 1,
            "discount_id": [
                1
            ],
            "priority": 1
        },
        {
            "amount": 143.8,
            "price_list_id": 1,
            "discount_id": [
                20,
                22
            ],
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "amount": 193.8,
            "price_list_id": 1,
            "discount_id": null,
            "priority": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

The input is: currency, array of discount ids, array of price list ids and price.

I need to match all prices based on given input, sort them via priority and then compare the highest priority price (lowest number) with given amount. When no product price matches given discount ids (doesn't have to match all ids, one is enough), then price with null `discount_id` value is used.

I'll provide an example. A customer is filtering products by price. The minimum amount is 100 USD and maximum amount is 150 USD. Let's say the price list is id 1.

1. There is a discount with ID 20 available for this customer. So this query matches price with priority 2.
2. There is no discount available. So this query matches price with priority 3, BUT the price is above given range so customer sees no product.

Also when customer is available to get a discount, but some product doesn't have such discounted price for given discount id, then price where `discount_id` == null is applied.

I'd like to avoid scripting, but can't figure out this by myself.

Comment: please provide a sample of what search result you expect?

Comment: My expected results are identifiers of root documents those matched given filters. And these prices are just one piece of many filters, but other filters are working fine. This example is just one nested attribute of the product.